# Deprecate Paging Parameters

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, url, pagination

I recently had a request to rename the spring REST paging parameters "page" and "size" to "pageIndex" and "pageSize".  My controller takes a Pageable object as a parameter.  That said, I understand that I can rename these parameters by setting the following properties like so:

```
spring.data.rest.page-param-name=pageIndex
spring.data.rest.limit-param-name=pageSize
```

However, because the API I'm developing on is actively being used by other developers, I need to **deprecate** rather than remove the "page" and "size" parameters (while continuing to have the api respect their values) while simultaneously supporting the new pageable parameter names.  I have looked through various documentation and articles, and after a day of searching, it is still not clear to me how to achieve this task.

My controller method looks something like this:

```
@ApiPageable
@RequestMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public Page<MyBean> getBeans(@RequestParam(required = false) final String blah,
                               final Pageable pageable) {

    return someService.doSomething(blahStr, pageable); 
}
```

Thanks in advance and, if during my day of searching, I might have missed the crucial piece of documentation I was looking for, kindly point me in its direction and accept my apologies.

**EDIT:**
To clarify this question a bit... The renaming did not involve changing the url.  In fact the URL must remain identical.  Instead, what is being renamed are a set of *url paging parameters*.  To be clear, if the end point to which this question pertains looks like this and is excepting a set of common paging parameters commonly used in some permutation or combination of (but not limited to) the following:

```
/beans
/beans?page=2
/beans?size=5
/beans?page=2&size=5
/beans?sort=created,ASC&page=4&size=6
```

...then creating a second endpoint with the same URL (but with all of the parameters with required marked as false), gives me an ambiguous mapping when I try to run the API.  Thus, unless there is slick way to distinguish these endpoint (both the endpoint using the deprecated params and the new one using the new params) this solution seems will require more than two endpoints, ...*or preferably there is a slick "silver bullet" way of handling this problem*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use two end points: one with the deprecated API and one for the new one. In the deprecated API convert deprecated parameters to the new ones, call your internal service, convert response to the deprecated response.

Later on, after all clients migrated to the new API, or after predefined migration period, you can decide to delete the deprecated end point.

**Update**

For the clients that cannot (or don't want yet) use changed API provide an end point that implements the old API. This method can look as follows:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/oldapi/...")
public Page<MyBean> getBeans(
    @RequestParam(required = false) final String blah,
    @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
    @RequestParam(value = "pageNum", required = false) Integer pageNum,
    @RequestParam(value = "sort", required = false)
) {
    // Create Pageable object from request parameters
    ...
    // Call service or repository with this pageable
    ...
}
```

In this method you can use any parameters names. For those who needs old names, you can keep old names.

To the number of the end points: I meant exactly 2 end points: one whose API names remain unchanged and one that changes (you wrote *I recently had a request to rename ...*)

**Update 2**

The good way to support 2 version of API is to use *2 end points*. If if you want to provide 2 APIs via single end point, this can be pretty error prone. In simple cases it is possible. For instance, you define your method as follows:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/oldapi/...")
public Page<MyBean> getBeans(
    @RequestParam(value = "size", required = false) Integer size,
    @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page,
    @RequestParam(value = "pageIndex", required = false) Integer pageIndex,
    ...
) {
    Integer pSize = pageSize != null ? pageSize : size;
    Integer pIndex = pageIndex != null ? pageIndex : page;
    ...
}
```

Keeping such code can be pretty complex. For instance, if some parameters are mandatory, it is complex and error prone to implement it in a single end point but very easy if you have 2 different end points. I *discourage* you from using such approach.

My suggestion: To those who want to use deprecated API provide a separate end point. They don't have to change their code, only change configuration parameter to point to a the end point with deprecated API. This is a normal price for them if they want to still use deprecated API.

Comment: How about the scenario where you have a pageable parameter which includes a size, page, and sort parameter (all of which have now been renamed)?  You would almost certainly need to create more than two endpoints, correct?  Seems like there should be an easier way... if not though I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Updated the question details in response to your updated answer.  Thx in advance!